# jQuery clone onchange breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I want an "add row" function. What I'm doing is when the button is pressed the row is cloned then appened, and the id's, names of form elements, and onchange events are changed. All of this works except the onchange function always calls the latest id. So there are say 3 rows (id's 1, 2, and 3) and I trigger on change for row 2, row 3 gets passed to the handler instead of 2.

Here is the script:

```
function addRow(){
    count = parseInt($("#hidden_count").val())
    count++     
    $("#hidden_count").val(count)       

    var row = $("#add_box").prev().clone()
    row.attr("id", "row_" + count)
    row.children().each(function(index, elem){
        if(elem.id.indexOf("delete_col_") != -1){
            elem.id = "delete_col_" + count
            $(elem).empty()
            $(elem).append("<div class='table-row-delete' onclick='deleteRow("+count+")'></div>");
        }else{
            $(elem).children().each(function(index, elem){
                if(typeof elem.name != 'undefined'){
                    if(elem.name.indexOf("exhaust_filter_num") != -1){
                        elem.name = "sheet[exhaust_filter_num_" + count + "]"
                        elem.value = parseInt(elem.value) + 1
                    }else if(elem.name.indexOf("exhaust_filter_size") != -1){
                        elem.name = "sheet[exhaust_filter_size_" + count + "]"  
                        elem.id = "exhaust_filter_size_" + count
                        elem.onchange = function() { calculateRow(count) }
                    }else if(elem.name.indexOf("exhaust_velocity") != -1){
                        elem.name = "sheet[exhaust_velocity_" + count + "]"                             
                        elem.id = "exhaust_velocity_" + count
                        elem.value = 0
                        elem.onchange = function() { calculateRow(count) }
                    }else if(elem.name.indexOf("exhaust_cfm") != -1){
                        elem.name = "sheet[exhaust_cfm" + "_" + count + "]"     
                        elem.id = "exhaust_cfm_" + count
                        elem.value = 0
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })

    row.insertBefore("#add_box")
}
function calculateRow(id){
    var filter = $("#exhaust_filter_size_" + id).val()
    console.log("Calc row: " + id + ", " + filter)
    var velocity = parseInt($("#exhaust_velocity_" + id).val())
    var cfmElem = $("#exhaust_cfm_" + id)

    var cfm = velocity * filterData[filter].freeArea * filterData[filter].kFactor
    cfmElem.val(cfm)
}
```

The orignal html is layed out like this (it is long so this is a stripped version):

```
<table>
    <tr id="row_1">
        <td><input onchanged="calculateRow(1)" /></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr id="add_box" align="center">
    <td colspan="5"><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow();"/></td>
        <input type="hidden" id="hidden_count" value="1" />
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `count` a local variable with the `var` keyword:

```
var count = parseInt($("#hidden_count").val());
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! Out of curiosity, why did that cause the problem? Even if count wasn't local, shouldn't it have been overwritten each time the function was called?